# How to use IPv6 with NodeJS https.request()

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, request, ipv6

I have written a program that exercises the REST API of an embedded device that my team is developing. The code that issues the https requests looks like this:

```
    var options = {
        hostname: hostAddress,
        port: hostPort,
        path: path,
        method: methodName,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Content-Length": post_data.length
        }
    };

    // Request and callback
    var request = https.request(
        options,
        function onResponse( response ) {
            // response code happens in here ...
        }
    );
```

This code works just fine when `hostAddress` is an IPv4 address, e.g. "192.168.1.13". But we've recently added IPv6 support onto the embedded device and that needs to be tested as well. However, the same code above does *not* work when the `hostAddress` is an IPv6 address.

The documentation for https.request() [here: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html ] doesn't say anything about IPv6. I have tried using each of the following values for the `hostAddress`, but without success.

```
hostAddress = "fe80::9eb6:54ff:fe90:8b70%eth0";
hostAddress = "[fe80::9eb6:54ff:fe90:8b70%eth0]";
hostAddress = "fe80::9eb6:54ff:fe90:8b70";
hostAddress = "[fe80::9eb6:54ff:fe90:8b70]";
```

I know the IPv6 address is correct -- I copied and pasted it from an ifconfig call on the embedded system host.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node version 0.12 doesn't support IPv6 on DNS binding, and since `request` utilizes that, it also won't work.

Per [this thread](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/5087), it's scheduled for implementation in v0.13.

**Update**

As of 2015, this appears to now be implemented in the main nodejs/node project (the re-amalgamation of Node.js and io.js).

```
http = require('http');
server = http.createServer();
server.listen(9000, '::');
```